# ionic multiple header bar?

Tags: ionic-framework, header

i have created new app with tabs. i want a header bar below tabs. how to get it?
even if i get a div which displays content below tabs its fine.

[the hide div is in the child page of tab i wanted to keep in a different page and add it below tabs so that it appears in all the pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJWet.png)

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

<!-- Dashboard Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Live View" icon-off="ion-ios-speedometer" icon-on="ion-ios-speedometer" href="#/tab/dash">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-tab>

 <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Statistics" icon-off="ion-stats-bars" icon-on="ion-stats-bars" href="#/tab/account">
   <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

   <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-ios-home" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
   </ion-tab>

   <ion-tab title="Service" icon-off="ion-clipboard" icon-on="ion-clipboard" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

   <!-- Chats Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-chatbox-working" icon-on="ion-chatbox-working" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>

  <!--<h1>Hide the DIV: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck"></h1>
   <div id="divslide" ng-hide="myCheck"></div>-->



 <!--<h1>Hide the DIV: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck"></h1>
  <div id="divslide" ng-hide="myCheck"></div>-->

   <ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
    <ion-content class="padding">
     <h1>Hide the DIV: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck"></h1>
      <div id="divslide" ng-hide="myCheck"></div>
       <h2>Welcome to Ionic</h2>
        <p>
       This is the Ionic starter for tabs-based apps. For other starters and ready-made templates, check out the <a href="http://market.ionic.io/starters" target="_blank">Ionic Market</a>.
       </p>
       <p>
      To edit the content of each tab, edit the corresponding template file in <code>www/templates/</code>. This template is <code>www/templates/tab-dash.html</code>
       </p>
      <p>
  If you need help with your app, join the Ionic Community on the <a href="http://forum.ionicframework.com" target="_blank">Ionic Forum</a>. Make sure to <a href="http://twitter.com/ionicframework" target="_blank">follow us</a> on Twitter to get important updates and announcements for Ionic developers.
   </p>
    <p>
  For help sending push notifications, join the <a href="https://apps.ionic.io/signup" target="_blank">Ionic Platform</a> and check out <a href="http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-overview" target="_blank">Ionic Push</a>. We also have other services available.
    </p>
  </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out the solution.
just add a peace of code in index file

```
 </ion-nav-bar>
   <ion-nav-bar class="has-tabs">
   <div class="bar-stable bar-subheader no-tap-scroll" id="divslide"></div>
  </ion-nav-bar>
```

thais it... it works..